# Множество слов с древним корнем "я-/ня-/ым-/ним-/им-/ём-/ем-/йм-" составляют половину русского языка

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова, корень-слова

Заинтересовался я как-то древним глаголом "прият" (принял, насколько я понимаю) и к удивлению обнаружил его корни в огромном множестве повседневных, на первый взгляд самых разных слов. Однако если задуматься, то все эти слова действительно можно объединить под общим знаменателем. Назовем этот знаменатель корнем **"я-/ня-/ым-/ним-/им-/ём-/ем-/йм-"**. Почему я говорю корнем? Сейчас объясню. В стандартной трактовке корни такие:

```
Воспринимать=> Восприним
Принять=> Приня
Занимать => Заним
Поднимать => Подним
Обнимать => Обним
Взять => Взя
Снять => Сня
```

Но если присмотреться, то многие из этих новых "корней" являются навешиванием разного рода приставок **пере/за/из/итп** на древний корень **я-/ня-/ым-/ним-/им-/ём-/ем-/йм-**. Семантика здесь тоже прослеживается общая:

```
Воспринимать=> Вос(при(иметь))
Принять=> При (иметь)
Занимать => За (иметь)
Поднимать => Иметь Под 
Нанимать => На (Иметь)
Обнимать => Об (иметь)    
Изъять => Из (иметь)
Взять => Вз (иметь)
```

В словарях тоже говорится о **родственности** чуть ли не половины слов русского языка:

**РОДСТВЕННЫЕ СЛОВА**

> глаголы: ять, взнять; иметь, иметься; имать; емлить; в-: внимать,
> внять; в(о)з-: взимать, взиматься, взымать, взыматься, взнимать,
> взъемлить, взять, взяться, взяточничать, возыметь; вос-при-:
> воспринимать, восприниматься, воспринять, восприять; вы-: вынимать,
> выниматься, вынуть, вынуться, вынять; до-: донимать, донять; за-:
> заиметь, заимствовать, заимствоваться, занимать, заниматься, занять,
> заняться; за-с-: заснять, засняться; из-: изъять, изымать, изыматься;
> на-: наёмничать, нанимать, наниматься, нанять, наняться; на-за-:
> назанимать, назаниматься; на-об-: наобнимать, наобниматься; на-от-:
> наотнимать, наотниматься; на-под-: наподнимать, наподниматься;
> на-при-: напринимать, наприниматься; на-с-: наснимать, насниматься;
> не-: ненять, неймёт, неймётся, неймут, неняться, неимать, неять;
> недо-по-: недопонимать, недопонять; об-: обнимать, обниматься, обнять,
> обняться, объять; от-: отнимать, отниматься, отнять, отняться,
> отыметь, отъять; от-с-: отснять; пере-: перенимать, перениматься,
> перенять; пере-за-: перезанимать, перезаниматься, перезанять; пере-с-:
> переснимать, пересниматься, переснять, пересняться; по-: поиметь,
> поймать, пойматься, понимать, пониматься, понять; по-за-: позанимать,
> позаниматься; по-на-: понанимать, понаниматься; по-на-при-:
> понапринимать; по-об-: пообнимать, пообниматься; по-от-: поотнимать,
> поотниматься; по-при-: попринимать; по-с-: поснимать, посниматься;
> под-: поднимать, подниматься, поднять, подняться, подымать,
> подыматься; под-за-: подзанимать, подзанять, подзаняться; под-с-
> подснимать, подснять, подсняться; пред-при-: предпринимательствовать,
> предпринимать, предприниматься, предпринять; при-: приимать,
> принимать, приниматься, принять, приняться, приять; при-под-:
> приподнимать, приподниматься, приподнять, приподняться, приподымать,
> приподыматься; про-: пронимать, пронять; про-за-: прозаниматься; раз-:
> разнимать, разниматься, разнять, разняться, разъять, разъяться; с-:
> снимать, сниматься, снять, сняться; у-: унимать, униматься, унять,
> уняться; сложные: лихоимствовать, мздоимствовать

[Ссылка на источник](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C#:%7E:text=%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C,%E2%97%86%20%D0%98%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%84%D0%B0.&text=%D0%98%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%8E%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0.)

Таким образом, можно видеть, что источники путаются в показаниях. По новой трактовке есть различные корни типа "Восприним, переним". А в других словарях говорится о корнях типа **я-/ня-/ым-/ним-/им-/ём-/ем-/йм-**
Можно даже, осмелев, сказать, что половина русских слов произошла от одного и того же корня (с точностью до произношения), связанного с глаголом "иметь".

А вопрос такой: где можно поподробнее почитать об этом феномене?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

О чередованиях корней на -им,-ин можно почитать по ссылке https://lektsii.org/3-119070.html

О связанных корнях: https://peskiadmin.ru/chto-takoe-svyazannye-korni-v-russkom-yazyke-kornevaya-morfema.html

Здесь подробно рассказывается о сужении семантического поля корня в пределах одного слова, об изменении его внешнего вида.

> связанными корнями, в большинстве случаев, становятся те, которые в
> праславянский период претерпели воздействие закона слоговой гармонии,
> в результате которого произошло изменение внешнего облика слова. В
> числе фонетических процессов, происходивших с корнями на пути их
> преобразования из свободных ядерных морфем в связанные, -
> монофтонгизация дифтонгов и дифтонгических сочетаний с последующей
> утратой назальности монофтонгизированными гласными. Развитие протеза
> перед гласным в позиции начала слова (появление и протетических),
> дефонологизация дифференциального признака долготы также
> способствовали появлению корней с изменённой звуковой оболочкой,
> чередованиями, коней, предрасположенных к утрате самостоятельности и
> свободы. В большинстве слов отмечен словообразовательный процесс
> переразложения морфемных границ.

А ещё лучше - взять учебник по исторической грамматике, там всё есть - и история чередований корней, и монофтонгизация дифтонгоидов, утрата носовости,  процесс переразложения основы , который привел к присоединению -н’- к корню, изменение корневой семантики.